# Need to drop 900+ postgres schemas but it wants me to vacuum first

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have 900+ postgres schemas (which collectively hold 40,000 tables) that I'd like to drop. However, it appears that it wants me to vacuum everything first, because I get this whenever I try to drop a schema.

```
ERROR:  database is not accepting commands to avoid wraparound data loss in database
```

Is there a way to drop a large number of schemas without having to vacuum first?

Comment: That's a lot of tables... are they programatically referenced? If so a truncate of the tables will then allow the dropping of the schema no problem if you don't want to backup the data

Comment: The real question is: how did you get there? Did you disable auto-vacuum? If yes, why?

Answer (score 2):

IS there any problem is running the vacuum command. It is like a garbage collection for a database. I use postgre database and I use this command before doing any major work like backup or creating a sql scripts of the whole database.

**[VACUUM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-vacuum.html)** reclaims storage occupied by dead tuples. In normal PostgreSQL operation, tuples that are deleted or obsoleted by an update are not physically removed from their table; they remain present until a VACUUM is done. Therefore it's necessary to do VACUUM periodically, especially on frequently-updated tables.

Comment: unfortunately `VACUUM` is taking a really long time on some of our tables, and given the number of tables we have that need vacuuming, I was hoping there was an alternative approach

Comment: Yes I know it takes a long time. In your case, I can imagine you have to wait maybe for the whole night :) but this is the best way of removing tuple.

Answer (score 0):

You've  got two choices. Do the vacuum, or drop the whole database. xid wrap-around must be avoided.

https://blog.sentry.io/2015/07/23/transaction-id-wraparound-in-postgres

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do, except VACUUM oder dropping the database.

In addition, if you don't do the VACUUM, the database will not work for anything, not just for the schemas you want to drop.